# Docker ENTRYPOINT with ENV variable and optional arguments

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile with an ENTRYPOINT that uses an ENV variable. I can't get the ENTRYPOINT structured so the container can also accept additional command line arguments. Here is the relevant part of the Dockerfile:

```
ARG MODULE_NAME
ENV MODULE_NAME=$MODULE_NAME
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/python3 -m ${MODULE_NAME}
```

That works fine if I just want to launch the container without additional arguments:

```
docker run my-image
```

But I need to be able to pass additional command line arguments (e.g., a "--debug" flag) to the python process like this:

```
docker run my-image --debug
```

With the form of ENTRYPOINT above, the "--debug" arg is not passed to the python process. I've tried both the exec form and the shell form of ENTRYPOINT but can't get it to work with both the ENV variable *and* command line args. A few other forms I tried:

This runs but doesn't accept additional args:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/python3 -m ${MODULE_NAME}"]
```

This gives "/usr/bin/python3: No module named  ${MODULE_NAME}":

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/python3", "-m ${MODULE_NAME}"]
```

This gives "/usr/bin/python3: No module named  ${MODULE_NAME}":

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/python3", "-m", "${MODULE_NAME}"]
```

Comment: Did you try to set `MODULE_NAME` when run container? `docker run -e MODULE_NAME=<NAME_HERE> my-image`?

Comment: this is wrong `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/python3 -m ${MODULE_NAME}"]` it may be `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/python3" , "-m",  "${MODULE_NAME}"]`

Comment: what gives `docker exec -it your_container echo ${MODULE_NAME}`?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar That may work but I haven't tried it because the intent is to bake the module name into the image. Users should not need to know what module is being run.

Comment: @user2915097 `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/python3" , "-m", "${MODULE_NAME}"]` does not work. It causes the container to exit immediately, rather than actually run the python module. I assume it is because it is passing "-m" and "${MODULE_NAME}" as args to bash instead of python.

Comment: makes sense, can you launch your container `docker run my-image echo ${MODULE_NAME}` and see what it displays, to check that MODULE_NAME is set?

Comment: @user2915097 Running `docker exec -it your_container echo ${MODULE_NAME}` starts the python interpreter. But if I then look at `os.environ`, `MODULE_NAME` is set correctly.

Comment: I've noticed that the python help section states at `-m mod : run library module as a script ` option that it **`(terminates option list)`**. Have you checked if this is your case?

Comment: @tgogos Where do you see this? `-c` terminates python options but `-m` does not.

Comment: `python3 --help` gives me a `-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)`

Comment: That is a typo in the documentation. If I create a file "foo.py" that contains "import sys; print(sys.argv)", then call "python3 -m foo a b c", `sys.argv` contains all the command line arguments.

Comment: My bets are it would have something to do with the fact that Entrypoints are static and non-overridable. I don't think it's parsing the input. Have you tried CMD instead? SInce it's overrideable by image and execution?

Comment: @Dockstar I considered CMD but the problem there is when you give a command line arg, it bashes all of the previous arguments, whereas I want to append. It seems the fundamental problem is that the array form of ENTRYPOINT does not do variable expansion.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It appears it isn't possible to create an ENTRYPOINT that directly supports both variable expansion *and* additional command line arguments. While the shell form of ENTRYPOINT will expand ENV variables at run time, it does not accept additional (appended) arguments from the `docker run` command. While the exec form of ENTRYPOINT does support additional command line arguments, it does not create a shell environment by default so ENV variables are not expanded.

To get around this, `bash` can be called explicitly in the exec form to execute a script that then expands ENV variables and passes command line args to the python process. Here is an example Dockerfile that does this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ARG MODULE_NAME=foo
ENV MODULE_NAME=${MODULE_NAME}

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3.5

# Create the module to be run
RUN echo "import sys; print('Args are', sys.argv)" > /foo.py

# Create a script to pass command line args to python
RUN echo "/usr/bin/python3.5 -m $MODULE_NAME \$@" > /run_module.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/run_module.sh"]
```

Output from the docker image:

```
$ docker run my-image
Args are ['/foo.py']

$ docker run my-image a b c
Args are ['/foo.py', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Note that variable expansion occurs during the RUN commands (since they are using shell form) so the contents of run_script.py in the image are:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 -m foo $@
```

If the final RUN command is replaced with this:

```
    RUN echo "/usr/bin/python3.5 -m \$MODULE_NAME \$@" > /run_module.sh
```

then the run_script.sh would contain

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 -m $MODULE_NAME $@
```

But output from the running container would be the same since variable expansion will occur at run time. A potential benefit of the second version is that one could override the module to be run at run time without replacing the ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: I don't like to accept my own answers but since there hasn't been another in nearly a month...

Comment: I too had this same issue with environment variables not expanding in ENTRYPOINT and in our case could bake the variables in the build tool such that when it generated docker file they were no longer parameterized.  In your case it doesn't look like that is an option.

Comment: seems to be still in 2020 the only solution. Thanks for sharing. Works perfectly in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the ENV variables resolved inside ENTRYPOINT. The mistake I was making was the ARGs that were used to populate ENV were written before the FROM statement and was hence out of scope for the current docker stage. Once I moved them below FROM, it works great.

My working Dockerfile:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

ARG NEO4J_USERNAME
ARG NEO4J_URL
ARG NEO4J_PASSWORD

ENV NEO4J_USERNAME=$NEO4J_USERNAME \
         NEO4J_URL=$NEO4J_URL \
         NEO4J_PASSWORD=$NEO4J_PASSWORD

COPY ./ /
WORKDIR /

ENTRYPOINT python3 -u myscript.py ${NEO4J_URL} ${NEO4J_USERNAME} ${NEO4J_PASSWORD}
```

Comment: Good point about needing to put the ARGs after the FROM statement. But it doesn't appear that this addresses the ability to pass additional arguments to the python script in the `docker run` command.

Comment: why is that you have same name for arg and env, both of them serve 2 different purposes ? Also you are passing ARG to the Entrpoint not the ENV variable.